# How to source setup.bash with catkin build?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, build, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm having some problems with catkin build for my workspace. I've followed the next steps:

1. $ mkdir -p ~/catkin_tools_ws/src
    1. $ source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
2. $ cd ~/catkin_tools_ws
    1. $ catkin init
3. $ catkin build
    1. $ source ~/catkin_tools_ws/devel/setup.bash

It builds correctly without errors or warnings, but if I type 'roscd' it sends me to `/opt/ros/melodic` and not to my workspace.

The weird thing is that if i create the workspace with catkin_make, it works perfectly.

Thanks for your time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317303/how-to-source-setup.bash-with-catkin-build?/) by [Billion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40303/billion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:
Are those really all the steps you do?

Because if you haven't `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` before step 2, `catkin init` should complain about "not extend[ing] any other result space", which woud lead to what you describe.

**Comment by [Billion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40303/billion/) on 2019-03-03**:
Hi gvdhoorn, yes I did it but i forgot to add it in the description. However when i source the setup.bash of my workspace, ROS_PACKAGE_PATH continues to be only '/opt/ros/melodic/share'...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-03**:
re: `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`: I would say that is normal, as you have no packages in your workspace as far as I can tell.

If you want more specific help, *edit* your original question to show us the exact steps you take when initialising and building your workspace.

**Comment by [Billion](https://answers.ros.org/users/40303/billion/) on 2019-03-03**:
Thanks to you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the update, but just making sure: I don't see a `cd ~/catkin_tools_ws` anywhere. Without that `catkin init` runs in the `CWD`, which I doubt is what you did/wanted.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0